# Can't get knockoutjs to work

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Tried to fiddle with knockoutjs for the first time, but can't get any examples to work:

What's wrong with this html page - it only displays "first name:" / "last name:" in my browser:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Knockout demo</title>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AppViewModel() {
            this.firstName = "Helena";
            this.lastName = "Christensen";
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
        <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Knockout demo</title>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
        <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function AppViewModel() {
        this.firstName = "Helena";
        this.lastName = "Christensen";
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the script tag with the ViewModel and ko.appyBindings call to the bottom of your body.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `window.onload` to trigger the binding process after browser window has loaded all elements:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Knockout demo</title>
    <script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function AppViewModel() {
        this.firstName = "Helena";
        this.lastName = "Christensen";
      }
      window.onload = function() {
        ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
      };
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
        <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```